# Preventing user from saving of web pages in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How i can prevent user to save web pages in asp.net.The user must need to login for accessing resources.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, bookmark? Save as a PDF?

Comment: This is handled by using one of the various authentication approaches. If the user saves the page markup and attempts to run it, authentication will stop them.

Comment: What do you mean by saving the page? is it the page source you refer to? Or do you want to stop the user from going to certain pages before they have logged in?

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to prevent a user from saving the markup in your web page.  Even with JavaScript, you won't have this ability.

Once a user is viewing a web page, it is on their machine and it is simply a visual representation of the markup that is there.

In summary: **you cannot prevent a user from saving the contents of a web page that they are viewing**.

If you are concerned with a user persisting content in a disconnected manner, your best bet would be to take a different approach:  something to do with legal rights and that sort of thing.  But that is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that a user can use your web page:

1. Downloading JavaScript files you've used (even the code you've written yourself)
2. Taking snapshots (pictures) of your rendered page
3. Saving your page
4. Printing your page
5. Seeing your page's source and copy/pasting its content

This generally means that you should not spend your time on preventing user from doing anything with what you send to him. Rather you should change your strategy (which of course, needs more explanation from your part).